# Can I add passenger support to a existed Nginx instead of rebuild one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a server running with nginx serving two php websites, right now I want to make it serving a rails app, I've googled, but there no notes about add passenger support to a existed nginx, all of them are telling me run passenger-install-nginx-module to build a nginx.

Can I add passenger support to my nginx instead of rebuild it?

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 2):

You still need to rebuild nginx. If you run passenger-install-nginx-module you will see this output:

> Nginx doesn't support loadable modules such as some other web servers do, so in order to install Nginx with Passenger support, it must be recompiled.

See [Installing Passenger as a normal Nginx module](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install_as_nginx_module.html) for steps.

```
cd /path-to-nginx-source-dir
./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx \
  --add-module=$(passenger-config --nginx-addon-dir) \
  --add-module=/path-to-some-nginx-module
make
sudo make install
```

The value for /path-to-passenger-module can be obtained with the command:

```
passenger-config --nginx-addon-dir
```

Comment: I'm missing something here...I can't run "passenger-config" because Passenger isn't installed. What is the step I am missing?

Comment: Install Passenger: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/tutorials/deploy_to_production/installations/oss/ownserver/ruby/nginx/

Comment: I did try installing Passenger, and then passenger-config returns a path, but there is no file at that location.

Comment: I have discovered that you also need to install passenger_devel with: sudo dnf install passenger-devel.x86_64. Otherwise the file won't exist. This may be a change since the question was first answered, and is missing from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to rebuild nginx if you use Phusion Passenger Standalone.

From [Passenger's wiki](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Why-can%27t-Phusion-Passenger-extend-my-existing-Nginx%3F#but-i-dont-want-to-recompile-nginx-are-there-alternatives):

> **"But I don't want to recompile Nginx. Are there alternatives?"**
>
> Yes. Use Phusion Passenger's Standalone mode. Phusion Passenger
>   Standalone is a standalone server. It does not extend Nginx so it does
>   not need to recompile Nginx. It will therefore work perfectly with
>   your existing Nginx installation.
>
> When using Passenger Standalone, you are supposed to:
>
> ```
> Start Passenger Standalone on a certain port or socket file.
> Add reverse proxy rules to your Nginx configuration file, to forward requests to Passenger Standalone.
> ```
>
> If you've ever used Unicorn and Puma, then using Passenger Standalone
>   will be very familiar: usage is almost the same.